# How to change the toc level depth?

Tags: asciidoctor

I have a asciidoctor page like:

```
:toclevels: 3

= 1
== 1.1
=== 1.1.1
== 1.2
= 2
== 2.1
=== 2.1.1
```

The general config is to display 3 level deep in the table of contents.
But e.g. for chapter 2 I only want to include the top level in the table of contents.

Is it possible to change the toc level per chapter?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you render one chapter at a time. If you are rendering say a whole book, then whichever value is found first wins for the entire document being rendered. I had the same issue and we started discussing it [on the list](http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Redefining-attributes-td3515.html).